# How do I resize a second picture with VBA in Powerpoint?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I managed to get a picture from Excel to Powerpoint via VBA. This method works perfectly fine. However, I'd like to reposition and resize the second picture.

Could you please help me out?

```
Sub ExceltoPP()

Dim pptPres As Presentation     
Dim strPath As String           
Dim strPPTX As String           
Dim pptApp As Object



    strPath = "D:\"
    strPPTX = "Test.pptx"       

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    pptCopy = strPath & strPPTX

    pptApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=pptCopy, untitled:=msoTrue

    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation   

    Sheets("NEW").Range("Table").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    pptPres.Slides(2).Select
    pptPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

    Set Graphic = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    With Graphic.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
      .Left = 0.39 * 72
      .Top = 2 * 72
      .Width = 5 * 72
      .Height = 2 * 72
    End With
```

Till this part it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to add the second picture, Powerpoint adds the picture, but the repositioning and resizing does not work.

```
Sheets("NEW").Range("A1:M14").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    pptPres.Slides(2).Select
    pptPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile

    Set Graphic2 = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    With Graphic2.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
      .Left = 0.39 * 72
      .Top = 5 * 72
      .Width = 5 * 72
      .Height = 2 * 72
    End With


    pptPres.SaveAs strPath & Range("company") & ".pptx"  
    pptPres.Close      
    pptApp.Quit
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note:`pptApp` represents the powerpoint application, so there is no need for `Set Graphic = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")`. Just use `pptApp`.

Comment: Untested, but I'd try referring to the shape by index... it should be the last shape on that slide so you could use `Shapes.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen has suggested, you can refer to the desired shape by index.  However, there's no need to invoke GetObject.  Try...

```
Sheets("NEW").Range("A1:M14").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
With pptPres.Slides(2)
    .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count) 'refers to last pasted shape
        .Left = 0.39 * 72
        .Top = 5 * 72
        .Width = 5 * 72
        .Height = 2 * 72
    End With
End With
```

Your code, though, can be re-written as follows...

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub ExceltoPP()

    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strPPTX As String
    Dim pptCopy As String

    strPath = "D:\"
    strPPTX = "Test.pptx"

    pptCopy = strPath & strPPTX

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:=pptCopy, untitled:=msoTrue)

    Sheets("NEW").Range("Table").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    With pptPres.Slides(2)
        .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count) 'refers to last pasted shape
            .Left = 0.39 * 72
            .Top = 2 * 72
            .Width = 5 * 72
            .Height = 2 * 72
        End With
    End With

    Sheets("NEW").Range("A1:M14").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    With pptPres.Slides(2)
        .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count) 'refers to last pasted shape
            .Left = 0.39 * 72
            .Top = 5 * 72
            .Width = 5 * 72
            .Height = 2 * 72
        End With
    End With

    pptPres.SaveAs strPath & Range("company").Value & ".pptx"
    pptPres.Close
    pptApp.Quit

    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing

End Sub
```